# Are cross site scripting attacks and sql injection a good topic for my thesis?

Tags: web-application, sql-injection, security-theater, secure-coding

So I'm doing my undergraduate thesis, I would like to explore how cross site scripting sql injections occur. And for the purpose of the thesis I'd also like to create a fictional website that is vulnerable to cross site scripting and sql injection and then evaluate the different ways that such attacks could be prevented by using vulnerability scanners and other methods. 
Though, I think this topic would be too simple for a thesis, does anyone have any suggestions on what else to add that would add some more complexity to this topic?

Thanks

Comment: Most universities provide counceling for students to pick a thesis topic. You should make use of that to find a topic which suits you and will have enough material to fulfill their requirements for a thesis.

Comment: Hi sky - while this is an interesting question it is not on topic here.

Comment: This is a poor choice for a thesis topic because these attacks are so well understood and it is a difficult topic to expand upon.  I would find a less popular topic.

Comment: @Rook, what about if I compare how different website built by different technologies respond to xss,sql injections?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it. Injection attacks have been in the wild for long time, and everyone (in this field) know about them.

As I see you are focusing on web applications, my suggestion is to take one of the vulnerabilities in the end positions of the OWASP's ranking, and then research about it.

Comment: hmm, sounds hope it's re searchable